# reference_wrapper<string> does not print in cout, but reference_wrapper<int> does?

Tags: c++, templates, reference-wrapper

Why the line where i am trying to print the "reference_wrapper for string" is giving error for unsupported operator<< for "reference_wrapper for string" but does not give on "reference_wrapper for int"?

```
int main(){

    int  s= 43;
    string str = "hello";

    reference_wrapper<int> x{s};
    reference_wrapper<string> y{str};

    x.get() = 47;
    y.get() = "there";

    cout<<"printing original int "<<s<<"\n";
    cout<<"printing original string "<<str<<"\n";

    cout<<"printing reference_wrapper for int "<<x<<"\n";
    cout<<"printing reference_wrapper for string "<<y<<"\n"; // gives error

    int& refint = x;
    string& refstr = y;

    cout<<"printing reference for int "<<refint<<"\n";
    cout<<"printing reference for string "<<refstr<<"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`operator<<` for `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) is a function template, when being passed a `reference_wrapper`, the last template argument `Allocator` fails to be deduced; because implicit conversion won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions).

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), which happens later.

As the workaround, you can call [`std::reference_wrapper<T>::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/get) explicitly or perform explicit conversion.

On the other hand, [`operator<<` for `int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is a non-template, then doesn't have such issue.